# Potential Bug: Setting value for undefined column using iloc

Tags: python, pandas

If you do

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,9), columns=['count'])
>>> df.iloc[0:5]['group'] = 'a'
>>> df
Out[346]: 
   count
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
```

no value will be set. However, if you first do

```
>>> df['group'] = 'b'
>>> df.iloc[0:5]['group'] = 'a'
>>> df
    Out[353]: 
   count group
0      0     a
1      1     a
2      2     a
3      3     a
4      4     a
5      5     b
6      6     b
7      7     b
8      8     b
```

For me, this is unexpected behavior. I would expect this to work no matter whether I subselect some of the columns using `iloc`. However, if that should not work, at least I expect an error / warning. The only time I expect no values to be set and no warning is when I set some values using indices and the index actually doesnt exist on the left-hand side.

I'm on

```
>>> pd.__version__
Out[355]: '0.14.0rc1-51-gccd593f'
```

Comment: Don't know whether this is a bug or not but `df.loc[0:5, 'group'] = 'a'` works with and without the initial column being created

Comment: you are chain indexing, see here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy ; use ix/loc

Comment: Shouldn't I get a "SettingWithCopy" error then?

Comment: @Jeff: Moreover, if I'm only setting only onto a copy: Why does it work if I create the column before setting the value? The second example then should keep column value `b` through all of it, since the second command again uses `iloc` and only sets the value on a copy.

Comment: its not always possible to figure this out; ``SettingWithCopy`` is a heuristic (it might be a bug that its not showing the warning though). this is 2 python operations that are completely independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not a bug: when you're calling

```
df.iloc[0:5]['group']
```

what happens "under the hood" is actually two calls:

```
m = df.iloc[0:5]
m['group'] = 'a'
```

and, as you can see, `df` is not changed at all. But, by doing:

```
df['group'] = 'b'
```

you actually changed `df`, and if you'll `print df` at this point you'll get another column full of `b`s:

```
   count group
0      0     b
1      1     b
2      2     b
3      3     b
4      4     b
5      5     b
6      6     b
7      7     b
8      8     b
```

so when you're continuing and doing:

```
df.iloc[0:5]['group'] = 'a'
```

you're changing the column that you've just added to `df`.

As Jeff mentioned in a comment above, according to the **[docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)**:

> Sometimes when you slice an array you will simply get a view back,
>   which means you can set it no problem. However, even a single dtyped
>   array can generate a copy if it is sliced in a particular way

Further:

---

[image]

This means that the designers of pandas allowed different behaviors (returning a view vs. returning a copy), probably to achieve performance, and in order not to fall into such unexpected behavior they warned you in the docs and provided the "right" way of usage which is `df.loc[0:5,'group'] = 'a'`

To conclude, this is not a bug - it's "by design"

Comment: In the second case then, again, the final command should be split up into two commands and it would do `m['group'] = 'a'` - in your words, `df` is not changed at all. If you're point at the same as Jeff is, that I'm setting the value on a copy: Why does it still set the value in the second example, but not in the first example? And moreover, why do I not get a `settingWithCopy` warning?